# Transpiling constant to javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am learning typescript, I have a simple code that creates a constant variable and prints it.

```
const versionNuber : number = 1.3;
console.log(versionNuber);
```

and after running a command `tsc` on the file generates following javascript code.

```
var versionNuber = 1.3;
console.log(versionNuber);
```

My question is how to transpile the constant to javascript?
Why `tsc` doesn't do that even though `const` is supported in javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html), there is a `target` option, which indicates the target language version to transpile the Typescript to. It defaults to ES3 (standardized in 1999; compatible with basically everything).

If you want to keep `const` from being turned into `var`, set the target to ES2015 or later. (`const` was not officially supported in JS before ES2015 - using it will throw in IE10, for example, which was released in 2012)

[Playground link with ESNext target](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?noImplicitAny=false&target=99#code/MYewdgzgLgBAbgUwE4QJbgHIFcBGyYBcMYWAtnkjALwwCMAdAMwDcAUKJCADYL1cgBzABSIU6MNgoBKZkA) showing `const` being preserved